# Differences between FASA's 1993 hardcover and softcover Earthdawn (#6000 and #6001)

Tags: earthdawn, fasa

Were there significant edits between the hardcover (#6000) and the (second printing of the) softcover (#6001) editions of FASA's original Earthdawn from 1993, or did they just fix typos? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any significant differences. My game group never encountered any situations where there was a difference between those two books in our many years of playing Eartdawn.